# Tensorflow restore model

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to restore my Tensorflow model -- it's a linear regression network. I'm sure I am doing something wrong because my predictions are not good. When I train, I have a test set. My test set predictions look great, but then when I try to restore the same model, predictions look poor.

Here is how I save the model:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    training_data, ground_truth = d.get_training_data()
    testing_data, testing_ground_truth = d.get_testing_data()

    for iteration in range(config["training_iterations"]):
        start_pos = np.random.randint(len(training_data) - config["batch_size"])
        batch_x = training_data[start_pos:start_pos+config["batch_size"],:,:]
        batch_y = ground_truth[start_pos:start_pos+config["batch_size"]]
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        train_acc, train_loss = sess.run([accuracy, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: testing_data, y: testing_ground_truth})
        test_acc, test_loss = sess.run([accuracy, cost], feed_dict={x: testing_data, y: testing_ground_truth})
        samples = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: testing_data})
        # print samples
        data.compute_acc(samples, testing_ground_truth)

        print("Training\tAcc: {}\tLoss: {}".format(train_acc, train_loss))
        print("Testing\t\tAcc: {}\tLoss: {}".format(test_acc, test_loss))
        print("Iteration: {}".format(iteration))

        if iteration % config["save_step"] == 0:
            saver.save(sess, config["save_model_path"]+str(iteration)+".ckpt")
```

Here are some examples from my test set. You'll notice `My prediction` is relatively close to `Actual`:

```
My prediction: -12.705  Actual : -10.0
My prediction: 0.000    Actual : 8.0
My prediction: -14.313  Actual : -23.0
My prediction: 17.879   Actual : 13.0
My prediction: 17.452   Actual : 24.0
My prediction: 22.886   Actual : 29.0
Custom accuracy: 5.0159861487
Training    Acc: 5.63836860657  Loss: 25.6545143127
Testing     Acc: 4.238052845    Loss: 22.2736053467
Iteration: 6297
```

Then here's how I restore the model:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, config["retore_model_path"]+"3000.ckpt")

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    pred = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: predict_data})[0]
    print("Prediction: {:.3f}\tGround truth: {:.3f}".format(pred, ground_truth))
```

But here's what the predictions look like. You'll notice that `Prediction` is always right around 0:

```
Prediction: 0.355       Ground truth: -22.000
Prediction: -0.035      Ground truth: 3.000
Prediction: -1.005      Ground truth: -3.000
Prediction: -0.184      Ground truth: 1.000
Prediction: 1.300       Ground truth: 5.000
Prediction: 0.133       Ground truth: -5.000
```

Here is my tensorflow version (yes I need to update):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
0.12.0-rc1
```

Not sure if this helps, but I tried placing the `saver.restore()` call after the `sess.run(init)` and I get predictions that are all the same. I think this is because `sess.run(init)` initializes the variables.

Change the ordering like this:

```
sess.run(init)
saver.restore(sess, config["retore_model_path"]+"6000.ckpt")
```

But then predictions look like this:

```
Prediction: -15.840     Ground truth: 2.000
Prediction: -15.840     Ground truth: -7.000
Prediction: -0.000      Ground truth: 12.000
Prediction: -15.840     Ground truth: -9.000
Prediction: -15.175     Ground truth: -27.000
```

Answer (score 2):

When you restore from checkpoint, you don't initialize your variables. As you noted at the end of your question.

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

That overwrites the variables, which you just restored. oops! :)

Comment those two lines out and I suspect you'll be good to go.